# Unable to solve org.json.JSON.typeMismatch in android

Tags: android, json

I'm currently having trouble with converting the following type of JSON data. I'm trying to display the book name and show the chapters and its contents in Android. However, I'm getting the JSON.typeMismatch error. I think that the code is not correct, but cannot find the problem. I've added my sample code below.

Some samples or tips will be helpful. I would love to hear from you!

```
(
    {
    "abbrev" : "abbrev"
    "book" : "name"
    "chapters": 
        (
            {"1": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}}, {"2": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}},
            {"2": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}}, {"2": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}},
            {"3": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}}, {"2": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}}
        )
    }
)
```

Here is some of my code that I tried. All I want to do is get the string data.

```
 mCreateJson = new CreateJsonData(this, "sample.json");
    JSONObject jsonObj = mCreateJson.getJsonObject(); ⇦ // Contains above json objects
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
            jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("chapters");
            android.util.Log.d("Test", jsonArray.toString());
            for(int a = 0; a < jsonArray.length(); a++ ) {

            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: JSON Array is represented by [] not by (). Is the json object you pasted is correct? Use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to format your json

Comment: use {} place of () ,{} is represent JSONObject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your json

```
{
"abbrev" : "abbrev"
"book" : "name"
"chapters": 
    [
        {"1": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}}, {"2": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}},
        {"2": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}}, {"2": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}},
        {"3": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}}, {"2": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}}
    ]
}
```

and parsing

```
 mCreateJson = new CreateJsonData(this, "sample.json");
JSONObject jsonObj = mCreateJson.getJsonObject(); ⇦ // Contains above json objects
JSONArray jsonArray;
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
        jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("chapters");
        android.util.Log.d("Test", jsonArray.toString());
        for(int a = 0; a < jsonArray.length(); a++ ) {
 JSONObject js = jsonArray.getJsonObject(a);
String ss1=js.getString("1");
//and so on as your json
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Json Data format is worng. It should be like this

```
    {
    "abbrev" : "abbrev",
    "book" : "name",
    "chapters": 
        [
            {"1": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}}, {"2": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}},
            {"2": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}}, {"2": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}},
            {"3": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}}, {"2": {"1": "...", "2": "..."}}
        ]
    }
```

After that you can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to parse your JSON data into Model classes and you can use GSON library to parse the data.